# Why is LinqToEntities Skip/Take oracle implementation so slow

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework, skip-take

Context is an Oracle Database, Entity Framework 5, LinqToEntities, Database First.

I'm trying to implement pagination over some large tables, my linqToEntities query looks like this :

```cs
context.MyDbSet
    .Include("T2")
    .Include("T3")
    .Include("T4")
    .Include("T5")
    .Include("T6")
    .Where(o => o.T3 != null)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Id)
    .Skip(16300)
    .Take(50);
```

Fact is, depending on how many records i wanna skip (0 or 16300) it goes from 0.08s to 10.7s.

It seems weird to me so i checked the generated SQL and here is how it looks like :

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
SELECT 
[...]
FROM ( SELECT [...] row_number() OVER (ORDER BY "Extent1"."Id" ASC) AS "row_number"
    FROM      T1 "Extent1"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 "Extent2" ON [...]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T3 "Extent3" ON [...]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T4 "Extent4" ON [...]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T5 "Extent5" ON [...]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN T6 "Extent6" ON [...]
    WHERE ("Extent1"."SomeId" IS NOT NULL)
)  "Filter1"
WHERE ("Filter1"."row_number" > 16300)
ORDER BY "Filter1"."Id" ASC
)
WHERE (ROWNUM <= (50) )
```

I checked if it actually was Oracle who took time through SQL Developper, and it is.

I then checked the execution plan and it's what appears :

[image: Execution Plan]

All i actually understand is that there's no STOPKEY for the first filter over row_number and that it probably fetch the whole sub query.

**I don't really know where to look at, if i'm not mistaken, the request is generated by ODT/ODP/.. and thus, should be optimized for an Oracle DB.. (and i can't change it myself)**

**Maybe my database model is rotten and i could add whetever indexes or optimization for it to work better ?**

Comment: The generated query looks correct, you probably need to index the column in the order by and perhaps more.

Comment: @Magnus All the columns on which i have a where or order by clause are already indexed.

Comment: What does the timing look like without all of the `Includes`?

Comment: You can't skip 16000 records and expect performance. Use partitions.

Comment: @Shoe There's still a difference from 0.03s to 0.08s. Not as big of a difference than with all the joins.

Comment: @TravisJ How would i implement partitionning if the order of my rows depends on user input ? Do you have any reference for it i could use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see all those UNIQUE SCAN subqueries?  That's doing a UNIQUE on every single one of those tables.

You should have a one-to-many relationship with T1 being the parent, and any tables you need to be in the query to have a `FOREIGN KEY` relationship to an indexed ID primary key column on T1.

Then you can use `Join` instead of `Include` and the subqueries will be unnecessary.

Comment: All FK are referenced over PKs, PKs are by nature indexed, and FK columns all have an index.Moreover, to my understanding, `UNIQUE SCAN` are the fastest way to access index table (and you can actually confirm that it's not the more expensive part when you check the cost given by explain ?)

Comment: Nope.  UNIQUE SEEK is faster - SCAN has to check every record, SEEK uses the index.  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/30/sql-server-index-seek-vs-index-scan-table-scan/

Comment: Then how do i get to having UNIQUE SEEK ? If that's the problem ? How is using Join any different from using Include SQL wise ? How are the subqueries unnecessary (they're implemented for the limit and seems mendatory) ?